# NameError: name 'path' is not defined

Tags: python

I tried to solve the problem by writing the following code but no luck.

```py
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
```

Then I saw an error like this

```
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your Tensorflow version?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

I just guess because the infomation you give is not enough. Just try it if your tensorflow has version issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to environment variables and add it to PATH.